What is this connector on this circuit board?
I have no clue how to use this connector. Right now I have wires shoved into it but I figure that there is an actual connector that fits.


Do you talk about "gold" one with text RXD on top (on the bottom of the picture)?

@RomeoNinov I think Luke is likely referring to the RXVCC and RXGND connectors.  Clarification is needed to be sure.  Luke?

@EndAntisemiticHate, can be :) Power lines for receiver?

@RomeoNinov That's a very good guess!  I think I've seen those connectors before... bug I can't recall where... they look so familiar though.

@EndAntisemiticHate, you are right, the OP mention they are wired. So with high probability the question is about them. About receiver: I see all the elements on the left side have something like RX (on right there is TX). But to identify we need info from the OP,

That circuit board is from a Broadcom Fiber Optic Industrial Evaluation Kit (circa 2010).  See this link for details:
https://www.broadcom.com/products/industrial-fiber-optics/eval-kits-accessories/industrial-eval-kits/hfbr-0410z
As it's currently written, your question is unclear as to which connectors you are referring, so to be most helpful, here is a link to the documentation (PDF), which includes all the connectors:
https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-2656EN
